# Opening attachments

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, attachments

When attaching documents using their link to sharepoint, they only seem to open in a browser then you have to open them in the application separately. Is there a way to directly open links to sharepoint to the application, e.g. Word or Excel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the SharePoint page should be replaced by the exact document link.

Find the document in the library, select the document and

- If its the modern UI, you would notice the copy link option to copy
  the document link.
- If it's the classic UI, clicking on the context menu or the 3 dots
  beside the individual document will pop up a preview with a link to
  the document on the bottom of the popup. Copy this link in this case.

Now, if the library is set up to open the document using a client application, it should work.